# Algebraic Data Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Hello I have only worked with imperative programming so far and I am learning Haskell :)

I have the following algebraic data types:

```
data Day   = I | ... | XXXI deriving(Ord,Eq)    (Days in roman numerals)
data Month = Jan | ... | Dec deriving(Ord,Eq)   (Months abbreviated to 3 letters)
data Year  = 0 | ... | 2021                     (actually Ints)
```

and I need to do some calculations with those. My first thought was mapping the Days and Months to Ints and do the calculations from there. For example:

```
dayConversionMap   = [(I,1), (II,2), (III,3), (IV,4), ... , (XXXI,31)]
monthConversionMap = [(Jan,1), (Feb,2), (Mar,3), ... , (Dec,12)]
```

My question is:

1. Is this a good solution for my problem?
2. How could i convert the Days/Months into Ints in a function given I have those maps.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you clarify which calculations you wish to do? If, for example, you wanted to be able to “add 1” to a month (e.g. go from Jan to Feb), you could derive `Enum` (assuming you put the months in order, since it defines the enumeration based upon that) and use `succ`. But that might be brittle because IIRC “adding 1” to Dec is an error with a derived `Enum`. If you want to work with dates as a whole, there should be date time libraries. Et cetera.

Comment: I want to calculate the minutes that elapsed from the date 1.1.0000 until X.X.XXXX (basically any date)

Comment: Note that, while this might be a fine learning exercise if you only want to cover the most common cases, getting dates right is very hard, and there are a lot of exceptions. For instance, there is no date 1.1.0000 since there is no year 0000: we went from year 1 BCE to 1 CE, without a "year 0" in the middle. Leap years, leap seconds, Julian-to-Gregorian transition, etc. A nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Don't, and I repeat **don't** do date and time calculations yourself. Ship out to [a good library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time). See also [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca) for an incomplete list of reasons to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your educative list of pitfalls when working with time and pointing out that it might not be a good idea to hande time on your own ;) will definetly keep this in mind! Altough in this case it is purely for the purpose of learning the tools of haskell :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

There are many ways of doing what you are looking for, and a practical way would be to use a library, as already pointed out. Even better, find a library and read the source code. [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Time&scope=set%3Astackage) is your friend.

---

But For learning Haskell purposes:

Instead of mapping them manually you could try provide a function. And because this is a behaviour you want more types to share you could create a Type Class.  One naive (maybe didactic, less so practical, maybe fun to play with) way would be:

1. Define a Class that provides a way to convert to and from Int, let's call it `ToInt`. Now you have a common interface of getting that behaviour out of all your Types

```
class ToInt a where
  toInt   :: a -> Int
  fromInt :: Int -> Maybe a
```

Now you can implement your `to` and `from` for your types and use them to convert.

```hs
instance ToInt Day where
  toInt x =  
    case x of
      I -> 1
      II -> 2 
--    ...

  fromInt x = 
    case x of 
      1 -> I
--    ...

instance ToInt Month where 
-- ...
```

```
calculation :: Day -> Month -> Year -> Int
calculation d m y = doSomething (toInt d) 
  where 
    doSomething :: Int -> Int 
    doSomething = ...
```

Note that this is a simple but **bad** example.

You can see the tedious nature of both implementation, and the limited help you get from the type checker. But once you start implementing something, you get a feel for what works and what not. Then you can search for how others deal with these issues in the actual libraries, [for example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.13/docs/src/Data.Time.Calendar.Days.html#Day).